# take files from folder and sort them by type

Tags: php

need help,
I have this file strukture:

files (folder)
    .pdf 
    .pdf
    .doc
    .doc
    .doc
    .zip
    .zip
index.php

I would like to display in index.php files from "files" folder, and sort them by type. Further I would like to display it like this:

For zip:

```
<div class="dopobrania_zip">
    <a href="file adress">file title</a>
</div>
```

For pdf:

```
<div class="dopobrania_pdf">
    <a href="file adress">file title</a>
</div>
```

For doc:

```
<div class="dopobrania">
    <a href="file adress">file title</a>
</div>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you already got any code?

Comment: i'm beginner and don;t know how to start...

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code probably you can find your way out.

```
//directory to list, you choose; here we’ll just use the webroot
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

//warning: `is_dir` will need you to change to the parent directory of what you are testing
//see <uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php#70005> for details
chdir ($path);

//get a directory listing
$dir = array_diff (scandir ('.'),
    //folders / files to ignore
    array ('.', '..', '.DS_Store', 'Thumbs.db')
);

//sort folders first, then by type, then alphabetically
usort ($dir, create_function ('$a,$b', '
    return  is_dir ($a)
        ? (is_dir ($b) ? strnatcasecmp ($a, $b) : -1)
        : (is_dir ($b) ? 1 : (
            strcasecmp (pathinfo ($a, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), pathinfo ($b, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 0
            ? strnatcasecmp ($a, $b)
            : strcasecmp (pathinfo ($a, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), pathinfo ($b, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
        ))
    ;
'));

//echo to screen
header ('content-type: text/plain');
print_r ($dir);
```

For more details in code click [here](http://camendesign.com/code/php_directory_sorting)